# How do I fix a "will never return since the success typing is [...] and the contract is.." from Dialyzer?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I am using Dialyzer to fix errors in Erlang code.

```
io:format(IoDevice, "[]");
```

This line produces the following error:

```
The call io:format(IoDevice::pid(),[91 | 93,...]) 
  will never return since the success typing is
  (atom() | binary() | string(),[any()]) -> 'ok' 
  and the contract is (Format,Data) -> 'ok' 
  when Format :: format(), Data :: [term()]
```

I am not able to understand what the problem is can anyone explain it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend to read [io manual page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html). Its usage is simple:

```
1> io:format("hello ~p~n", [world]). % ~n means newline
hello world
ok
2> io:format("hello ~p~n", [<<"world">>]).             
hello <<"world">>
ok
3> io:format("hello ~s~n", [<<"world">>]).
hello world
ok
```

In above dialyzer told you that `io:format/2` (`format/2` means function `format` which accepts 2 arguments) accepts an `atom()` or `string()` or `binary()` as 1st argument and a list with zero or more elements as 2nd argument. According to your code, dialyzer detects that `IoDevice` is an Erlang `pid()` not an `string()` or `binary()`.